# Proper word for "civil claim won"?

Tags: word-choice, idioms, meaning-in-context

Proper word for "civil claim won"? What is the English idiom if any? I am translating a legal text and the sentence is literally "state fees are awarded for the civil claim won"

Comment: I suspect the term "judgment" would figure in somehow.

Comment: "The Civil Court agreed  with the complainant(s) and the state was ordered to pay compensation for ...".

Answer (score 1):

There are a few terms in common use in the jurisdiction with which I am familiar.

**A Favorable Finding or Favorable Judgment** - Presumably this stems from the common verdict language where the jury/judge "finds the defendant guilty/not-guilty", but that is speculation on my part.

Another formulation is that fees are awarded to the **prevailing party**.

Comment: Actually in the original text, what is meant is costs and fees which, simply speaking, the judge said the losing party must pay. It is quite unpleasant to translate to English.

Comment: @peter.petrov Unless I misunderstand you, the second phrase does exactly that.  It is implied that the prevailing party (the winner) receives their costs and fees from the loser.

Comment: In a *civil action*, at least in the UK, there is no finding of guilt or innocence. Those matters are dealt with in a *criminal action*. *Civil actions* are all about the law of contract, the law of tort, and land law. And I would be surprised if that was not the case in the United States too.

Comment: @WS2 - You are correct as to the law in my jurisdiction.  As a quibble, there is no finding of innocence in UK criminal law either, merely guilty/not-guilty.

Comment: @EricHauenstein Quite right, I should have referred to findings of  *guilty and not guilty*. But even in a criminal trial where the accused is found *not guilty* will the judge necessarily award costs against the police, or whoever brought the prosecution. The judge has absolute privilege and is perfectly at liberty to say, to the effect *The jury may have found you not guilty, but so far as I'm concerned you are a rogue and a scoundrel. You are free to leave, but do not come to me looking for costs*. I know of one very important case where that happened.